# Where is the path defined for the windows "run prompt"

Tags: windows-7, path

Pressing Windows-R brings up the run-prompt.

I start programs from this all the time.  I installed a newer version of an application (devenv.exe) -- the old version is in a different directory, and I want to use the OLD version of devenv.exe.

I suspect its a path issue, but I've no idea where to find this.

Answer (score 3):

Turns out that this is controlled by a registry setting for Visual Studio.  I created two registry keys and then run them to change the registry at will.

devenv10.reg

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\devenv.exe]
@="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\\Common7\\IDE\\devenv.exe"
```

devenv12.reg

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\devenv.exe]
@="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\\Common7\\IDE\\devenv.exe"
```